# PHP - Audience accurate device location, possible?

Tags: php, geolocation

Wonder if we can track user's device location up to province level over even deeper level with PHP?

I noticed that we are only able to detect up to City level from user's IP:

```
<?php
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
?>
```

Do we really need to get the data from telco?

I just curious, sometimes when I reach a shopping mall, I will receive welcome message from the mall. I wish to do the similar thing to audience who visiting a shopping mall and browse my app. Is it doable without engaging telco?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thing to note; this isn't necessarily the devices location, it's usually just the IP's "last logged location" that you're getting. Most of the time it's accurate, or at least in the same vicinity. I've had an instance where an IP has read a completely different state from where it actually is (*via PHP*).

Comment: If you connect to the malls wifi then obviously they know you are at the mall. But to get more precise location I think in most countries there has to be a crime done and the police has to ask the internet provider about location of the IP.